# MacTeX Error: XeLaTeX: command not found

Tags: xetex, mactex

Now here is the thing. I upgraded my Mac to the OS X EI Capitan a few days ago. And now MacTeX is not working. When I try to typeset it, the console shows the following error:

`xelatex: command not found.`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

this is due to the new permission settings on Mac OS X El Capitàn.
[Here](http://tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html) you can find a way to configure everything properly.

In that page (from which I copy), we find that

**Cause of the problem:**
MacTeX installs a symbolic link `/usr/texbin` pointing to the TeX binaries. GUI applications use this link to find the binaries. But in El Capitan, the location `/usr` is reserved for Apple, and even users with root access are not allowed to write to that location.

**Solution:**
The solution to this problem is to relocate the link to `/Library/TeX/texbin`, and reconfigure GUI applications to look in this location. Consequently, MacTeX-2015 and BasicTeX-2015 write two links, `/usr/texbin` and `/Library/TeX/texbin`, when installing on systems earlier than El Capitan, and write `/Library/TeX/texbin` when installing on El Capitan. These installations configure shell applications to look for TeX in both locations. 
You, therefore, need only to reconfigure GUI, as instructed [here](http://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf).

*Reconfiguring TeXLive Utility:* Version 1.23 of TEX Live Utility automatically detects the loss of `/usr/texbin` under El Capitan
and prompts the user to automatically fix the problem. Previous versions need manual fixing:

- Open TeXLive Utility Preferences
- Click on Choose...
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>
- Enter `/Library/TeX` and click ok
- Double click on `texbin`

*Reconfiguring TeXShop:* As pointed out in [this document](http://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf), TeXShop versions from 3.52 onwards (July 2015) automatically redirect themselves to the correct link; if you cannot/want not update, you should:

- Open TeXShop Preferences
- Go in the *Engine* tab
- Change the Path settings for (pdf)TeX from `/usr/texbin` to `/Library/TeX/texbin`

And you should be good to go.

*Reconfiguring LaTeXit:*

- Open LaTeXit Preferences
- Go under Typesetting - Behaviour
- Change all paths that start with `/usr/texbin` with `/Library/TeX/texbin`

*Reconfiguring TeXWorks:*

- Go on the TeXWorks Preference, Typesetting Pane
- click on the + button in the Paths for TeX
- Click on the popup menu and select your hard drive
- Double-Click on Library and then TeX
- Click on `texbin` to select it and Click on the Choose button to add
  `/Library/TeX/texbin`. You can delete the `/usr/texbin` item by selecting it and
  clicking one the - button.

Comment: Would you mind expanding your answer and including the information that you only linked? If the link were to be invalid in the future, then this answer would be useless.

Comment: I tried adding some of the most valuable parts. I don't know if a copy and paste of the whole document is the right way to go...

Answer (score 5):

In my case after installing MacTex (on El Capitan) I was able to get a result for `xelatex --version` in a new terminal window but not in the existing one running jupyter notebook (after canceling the running instance).

Solution: **Close the terminal** running jupyter open the terminal again test if `xelatex --version` works now and run your `jupyter notebook` or whatever command again

Answer (score 1):

Things are in slightly different places since the accepted answer was written. I was able to fix the problem by adding the following line to my .bash_profile :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin
```

This adds the folder containing the various TeX utilities to your path. If you're not using bash you'll probably have to edit some other startup file for your shell. If you're reading this in the future the specific file path may have changed; I found it by opening the preferences in TeX Live Utility. The first line should be "TeX programs:" followed by a clickable path to the destination you want. (Don't click "Choose", as this will overwrite the default.) You can then do command-i to get the copy-pasteable path.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I installed MaxTex today, and I canot find any of those.