# Installing LaTeX El Capitan

Tags: installing, mactex, texworks, mac

I saw that some quite similar questions have already been asked on the forum, but, still, I can't find a way to solve my problem.

I've just installed the mactex package 2015 from https://tug.org/mactex/ and then installed TeXworks. Now, when I try to compile any file I get the following error message:[image]

It's in italian and it means that program "pdflatex" has not been found and that I need a TeX distribution like MacTex.

The point is that I've already installed the Mac distribution!

Any help?

Comment: TeXworks for mac problably still thinks latex is available through `/usr/texbin`, which Apple no longer allows. You will problemly need to tell TeXWorks to look via `/Library/TeX/texbin` (please check that `texbin` is actually in that location, my test Mac is currently being used else where)

Comment: he answer can be found in detail here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274179/mactex-error-xelatex-command-not-found/274181#274181 - so this might be a dublicate of that question.